# Is there any benchmark/stress tool for GT.M database

Tags: database-performance, gtm-database

I googling about it but no luck ,maybe GT.M is not a popular database for use

I also try HammerDB but it not support

Is there any benchmark tool for it or some way to write a stress script ,I only have JDBC driver to connect to GT.M

Answer (score 1):

[FIS GT.M](http://fis-gtm.com) itself includes a "universal" NoSQL database, that matches the common NoSQL use cases. As GT.M does not have an SQL engine, it cannot by itself be tested with a JDBC driver. There are several applications layered on GT.M that map relational tables to the data stored in a GT.M database, and you should look follow-up with the support channels / forums for the tool you are using.

Since GT.M includes a complete and capable programming language, depending on what you plan to accomplish with it, you can certainly model your workload and create your own benchmark to mimic your anticipated workload.